# How do you add a column containing mean value to a table in SAS without Proc SQL?

Tags: sas

I have a dataset and I want to include the average value of one of my variables in a new field. Is there a way to do this without using Proc SQL?

Comment: One way is to use Proc MEANS, SUMMARY or UNIVARIATE to compute your aggregate values, and then DATA step to merge those back into the original data set.  Another way is to use two DOW loops; the first to assemble values for computing a group-wise result and the second to apply the result to each member of a group

Answer (score 1):

Use PROC MEANS to calculate the stats and then merge it in.

```
proc means data=sashelp.class noprint;
    output out=avg_values mean(height)=avg_height;
run;

data class_data;
    set sashelp.class;

    if _n_=1 then
        set avg_values;
run;

proc print data=class;
run;
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This was tremendously helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Use proc means, output the mean average of your variable in a new dataset then merge this new dataset with the dataset in which you want to see the average value of your var

(output out = test mean=mean_var; run;)